# Get object of calling method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get the object method who called another function. I don't want its name, but the actual object.

So far, I got this.

```
import inspect

def info():
    stack_call = inspect.stack()
    cls_method = stack_call[1][3]
    cls_obj = stack_call[1].frame.f_locals["self"]
    cls_members = inspect.getmembers(cls_obj)
    my_obj = None
    for el in cls_members:
        if el[0] == cls_method:
            my_obj = el[1]
            break
    print(my_obj)


class Bob:
    def __int__(self):
        pass

    def jim(self):
        info()


test = Bob()
test.jim()
```

It does what I want to do, but I don't like having to go through the list to find the right method with its name.

I tried many things, but can't see how to make it better.

Would anybody have a better version?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why should `info` even assume it *is* called from a method?

Comment: The original code is much more complex. I simply put an example that does something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little different:

```
def info():
    stack_call = inspect.stack()
    cls_obj = stack_call[1].frame.f_locals[list(stack_call[1].frame.f_locals.keys())[0]]
    cls_method = getattr(cls_obj, stack_call[1][3])
    print(cls_method)
```